# Can't reference a label created in a method

Tags: c#, winforms

We just started learning winforms and we have to make a mock GUI. With a contextMenuStrip I can make new labels which look like folders.

```
private void makeFolder(int x, int y)
{
    Label lbl_folder = new Label();
    lbl_folder.Location = new Point(x, y);
    lbl_folder.Width = 75;
    lbl_folder.Height = 75;
    lbl_folder.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    lbl_folder.Image = Properties.Resources.folder;
    lbl_folder.Text = "New Folder" + folderindex;
    lbl_folder.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;

    canvas.Controls.Add(lbl_folder);

    folderindex++;

    lbl_folder.ContextMenuStrip = folderMenuStrip; //so I can use another contextMenuStrip on them
}
```

With another contextMenuStrip used on these folders, I would like for example to delete the right-clicked folder but I can't reach lbl_folder.

```
//I would like to do something like this
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_folder.Hide();
}
```

The name lbl_folder doesn't exists in the current context. How can I fix this?

Comment: ***Where*** you declare a variable determines its *scope*.  If you declare it in a method, it only exists there. (The control will of course exist on the form, but the `lbl_folder` reference just in the method)

Comment: Give the label a name:  `lbl_folder.Name = "lbl_folder";`  Then you can reference by that key: `canvas.Controls["lbl_folder"].Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating labels dynamically and attaching the context menu to each label, I suspect what you really want is the delete menu item to reference the label you are right clicking.

In that case, you can use the SourceControl of the ContextMenuStrip to provide that:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((Label)folderMenuStrip.SourceControl).Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `lbl_folder` in local scope (within a method) so you can only use that variable within it.  You have two options:

1. Declare the variable at form scope. So move the line `Label lbl_folder = new Label();` outside of `makeFolder`.

   ```
   private Label lbl_folder = null;

   private void makeFolder(int x, int y)
   {
       lbl_folder = new Label();
   ```
2. Inside of `deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click`, retrieve a new reference to the same control, via the form's [ControlCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g.

   ```
   var lbl = this.Controls.Find("NameOfControl", true)[0] as Label;
   ```

   or

   ```
   var lbl = this.Controls.Find("NameOfControl", true).OfType<Label>().Single();
   ```

   ...depending how comfortable you are with LINQ.

   You might also be able to get it from `canvas` more efficiently, depending how you have `canvas` scoped.

   ```
   var lbl = canvas.Controls.Find("NameOfControl")[0] as Label.
   ```

Comment: My problem with moving `Label lbl_folder = new Label();` is if it's outside it doesn't make a new folder everytime I run `makeFolder`. It just recreates the folder deleting the previous one instead of putting down a second one.

Comment: @cheesy - Move the *declaration* of the variable outside; keep the `new` statement inside. I'll edit the answer to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue about the scopes of your labels. If they were declared in your `makeFolder` method they you cannot be accessed from outside the method.

If you don't want to use the `FindControls` method of the Container. Then, you can keep references to your labels created in a `hashtable`or dictionary which is declared as instance property in the form itself.

Then, in your `makeFolder` add the label to it.

```
lbl_folder.Name = folderindex;
hashtable.Add(lbl_folder.Name, lbl_folder);
```

From anywhere in the form you can get the label from you hashtable and modify its properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    var menu = menuItem.GetCurrentParent() as ContextMenuStrip;
    var label = menu.SourceControl as Label;

    label.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this inside the `makeFolder` method:

```
lbl_folder.Click += (s, e) => lbl_folder.Hide();
```

I understand that this isn't the event that you're trying to respond to, but it should help you to understand how it can be done.

So your method would look like:

```
private void makeFolder(int x, int y)
{
    Label lbl_folder = new Label();
    lbl_folder.Location = new Point(x, y);
    lbl_folder.Width = 75;
    lbl_folder.Height = 75;
    lbl_folder.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    lbl_folder.Image = Properties.Resources.folder;
    lbl_folder.Text = "New Folder" + folderindex;
    lbl_folder.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;

    lbl_folder.Click += (s, e) => lbl_folder.Hide();

    canvas.Controls.Add(lbl_folder);

    folderindex++;

    lbl_folder.ContextMenuStrip = folderMenuStrip;
}
```

This works no matter how many time you call this method and how many folder are created.